# Printing whole panel on a JFrame Form with a button

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe

I'm currently making a proposal program with a little database in it and its been like 3 days and I still can't make a solution on this problem. I have been looking for an answer about this but all I see is a solution without a JFrame form.(if its little confusing JFrame Form is what I use on Netbeans to make my User Interface to make it easier for me. Its a User Interface builder). So back to the topic, every time I try to print my panel, it just prints the JTable of my panel and doesn't print the other components like labels and text fields. Please take a look at my code.

```
public void printComponenet(){

  PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

  pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
    public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
      if (pageNum > 0){
      return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
      }

      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
      AffineTransform originalTransform = g2.getTransform();

            double scaleX = pf.getImageableWidth();
            double scaleY = pf.getImageableHeight();
            double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        g2.scale(scale, scale);
            jPanel9.printAll(g2);

g2.setTransform(originalTransform);
      return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
  });
  if (pj.printDialog() == false)
  return;

  try {
        pj.print();
  } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        // handle exception
  }
}
```

the code below are the codes shown when i click customize code

```
productTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

productTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {

    },
    new String [] {
        "Catalogue", "XXX", "XXXX", "Total Unit Price"
    }
) {
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
        false, false, false, false
    };

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit [columnIndex];
    }
});



productTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        productTableMousePressed(evt);
    }
    public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        productTableMouseReleased(evt);
    }
});

jScrollPane2.setViewportView(productTable);

if (productTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
    productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
}
```

what should I do with this problem. I hope someone could really help me to fix this cause. I am getting out of time and my brain is exploding. I would appreciate every help. Thank you.

Comment: What does `jPanel9` contain? Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help remove any confusion

Comment: i am very sorry about this. i don't know where i am going to get the codes from the auto generated code for the panel but i will post the codes that are shown when i click 'Customize Codes' when i right click the panel.

Comment: As a personal side note, I'd advise against trying to print "live" components this way, there are so many edge cases to take into consideration.  I'd instead either recommend doing it all by hand OR, better yet, using something like Jasper Reports

Comment: *"code for the panel"* is part of the source code - it's auto generated by the Netbeans

Comment: so the only way is to remake my whole program? i've never heard of Jasper Reports. this is my first year on java pardon me.

Comment: Why not Google it? The GUI optimizes view for the screen but not for a printout, and so you don't want to mix the two as you're doing. I second either using JasperReports, or if the data is simple, then creating your own text file printout.